# vue-html don't print with html entities format

Tags: vue.js, html-entities

I am saving the following information with htmlentities

```
<i class='fa fa-user'></i>
```

In my database the information is saved as follows

```
&lt;i class='fa fa-user'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
```

I am receiving this information on my frontend with vue js. Iam using the v-html directive to print.

[image]

> And what I wanted is o print in html, like for example, when i save without htmlentities

[image]

```
Does anyone know how I could do this on the frontend with vue?
```

Comment: Maybe you have to unescape the html entities first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unescape the string first. Like so:

```
methods: {
  unescape(string) {

    //create an element with that html
    var e = document.createElement("textarea");
   
    //get the html from the created element
    e.innerHTML = string;

    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

and refer to it in your template:

```
<i v-html="unescape(here_your_html)"></span>
```